# User defined function in Redshift from R DBI

Tags: r, postgresql, amazon-redshift, r-dbi

I'm accessing Amazon Redshift DB (PostgresSQL) from within R using DBI package. I try to define this open source function [Colpivot](https://github.com/hnsl/colpivot/blob/master/colpivot.sql) to transpose a table:

```
colpivot.string <- "create or replace function colpivot(
    out_table varchar, in_query varchar, ...."

dbGetQuery(con,  colpivot.string)
```

My error:

Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  Create Function is not supported for language plpgsql.

How can I define this function and use it on my redshift table via R? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Redshift doesn't support user defined function, stored procedures, if you are trying to create stored procedure on Redshift.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html

Comment: Stored Procedures are now supported in Amazon Redshift from version 1.0.7287 (late April 2019). Please review the document ["Creating Stored Procedures in Amazon Redshift"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-overview.html) for more information on getting started with stored procedures.